# Как раздать одну роль Дискорд НЕСКОЛЬКИМ ЧЕЛОВЕКАМ за одну команду Discord.py

Tags: python, бот, discord, discord.py

Бот должен раздавать роли дискорд сервера нескольким людям за одно сообщение (команду) без использования реакций и доп.кнопок. Но я никак не могу это сделать. Получилось раздать роль только автору сообщения.
Что я делаю не так и как это исправить?

Код, дающий роль только автору этого сообщения:

```
import discord
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/", help_command=None)
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    member = ctx.message.author
    role_1 = member.guild.get_role("id of role")
    await member.add_roles(role_1)
    await ctx.channel.send(member)


client.run("token")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
members = [список_нужных_участников]
role_1 = member.guild.get_role("id of role")
for member in members:
    await client.add_roles(member, role_1)
```

Сам список формируйте из объектов `member`:

```
first = discord.utils.get(message.guild.members, name='Sam')
members.append(first)
```

---

**UPDATE**
Вот так должен выглядеть ваш код (нужно использовать контекст ctx):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/", help_command=None)


@client.command(name="test")
async def test(ctx):
    members = ['name1', 'name2']
    role_1 = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=role_id)
    for member in members:
        current = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.members, name=member)
        await current.add_roles(role_1)


client.run("API_key")
```

Comment: Instance of 'list' has no 'guild' member

Comment: @ЧерновАлексей Как вы заполняете список members?

Comment: member = ['Toolin#5256','LEBOT#2278'], + я и id использовал тоже самое происходит, и в саму переменную (не массив) вставлял и ник, и id. выскакивает одна и та же ошибка, только с меняющимся форматом переменных

Comment: @ЧерновАлексей Если правильно понял, то что вам нужно в апдейте ответа

Comment: https://prnt.sc/ufijte https://prnt.sc/ufik1r https://prnt.sc/ufikbc - есть ошибки, https://prnt.sc/ufilnv - нету ошибок. Почему так происходит?

Comment: @ЧерновАлексей изменил ответ с указанием что не так )

Comment: https://prnt.sc/ufjfuw

Comment: @ЧерновАлексей простите немного неправильно написал - исправил

Comment: Всё равно та же ошибка выскакивает prnt.sc/ufjfuw

Comment: @ЧерновАлексей Скорее всего проблема в получении роли надеюсь id вы не берете в кавычки, или попробуйте получать роль так - `role_1 = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=id_of_role)`

Comment: я не заключаю в кавычки id роли

Comment: @ЧерновАлексей если брать роль как я указал выше - у меня все работает

Comment: @ЧерновАлексей В UPDATE код, который у меня работает. Естественно нужно подставить значения вместо `role_id`,  `API_key`, и заполнить список имена участников

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_roles'

Comment: @ЧерновАлексей Имена используете с хештегом? Нужно брать просто имя

Comment: СПАСИБО))) Я 10 дней с этим мучался